# Changing shapes property with PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+, propertygrid

I have this combo box with three values(circle,rectangle,and line):

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
    {
        case "circle":
            {
                propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = c;
            }
            break;
        case "line":
            { 
               propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = l;
            }
            break;
        case "rectangle":
            {
                propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = r;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

r,c and l are new objects from circle,rectangle and line class.I have these shapes , printed on my panel and I want to be able to change their property through `PropertyGrid`(like changing a circles color). I've tried something like:

```
private void propertyGrid1_PropertyValueChanged(object s, PropertyValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch(propertyGrid1.SelectedGridItem.ToString())
    {
        case GridItem=Color
            {

            }
            .
            .
            .
    }

}
```

But I don't know how to do this properly. can you help me with this?

Comment: I would suggest an apply button. When you select a shape in your combo box, load its properties to the propertyGrid and let the user modify them, then he clicks the button himself, which takes the properties and redraws the shape.

Comment: how should this button function?

Comment: Well, instead of reading the propertyGrid during the editing with the _PropertyValueChanged, you read them all at once on a button click. The user would click the button after he is done with the editing of the properties.

Answer (score 1):

You should have some shapes which contains properties like location and color. Then in `Paint` event of a control like `PictureBox` or `Panel`, draw your shapes. When editing your shapes using `PropertyGrid`, it's enough to handle `PropertyValueChanged` event of `PropertyGrid` and call `Invalidte` method of the drawing surface control.

**Example**

To have such shapes, use Shapes which I created here in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575663/how-to-save-panel-as-binary-winform-c-sharp) and use these events:

```
ShapesList Shapes;
private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Shapes = new ShapesList();
    Shapes.Add(new RectangleShape() { Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100),
        Color = Color.Green });
    Shapes.Add(new RectangleShape() { Rectangle = new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100),
        Color = Color.Blue });
    Shapes.Add(new LineShape() { Point1 = new Point(0, 0), Point2 = new Point(150, 150),
        Color = Color.Red });
    this.panel1.Invalidate();
    this.comboBox1.DataSource = Shapes;
}
private void propertyGrid1_PropertyValueChanged(object s, PropertyValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.panel1.Invalidate();
}
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = this.comboBox1.SelectedItem;
}
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    Shapes.Draw(e.Graphics);
}
```

[image]