# How to serialize/deserialize PictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
[Serializable]
class GameObject : PictureBox
{
    public bool Solid;
    public bool Selected;
}
```

Is there any way to serialize `BackColor`, `Size`, `Location` etc...?

Comment: First of all no you can not serialize a picturebox. Second you seem to be making a game right? Then do not use pictureboxes for your GameObjects. Implement the GameObject as normal class and give it a show() function which draws itself on canvas using GDI+. This class will be serializable

Comment: @Curunir I don't want to save picturebox I want to save it BackColor,Location,and Size

Comment: This is an XY problem. You want to store your game object's state, but because your game objects inherit from PictureBox, you need to save the PictureBox's state as well. Stop what you're doing and start over. Don't inherit from PictureBox.

Comment: Yes but you should not rip single properties out of an object to serialize them. Have an object which is serializable as a whole, since if you start adding more and more properties things will get messy.

Comment: I made a test class Test and there is only one int Test = 3; 
So I want to serilize only that int just to know how it works and that's all
can you just show me the code how to serilize that Test,and to deserilize that Test

Comment: You don't need to serialize your control. Instead, you need to have a model and serialize the model. Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40575797/3110834) which is a good example of doing such task,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For temporary small type of objects I prefer to use structures, although you can use classes as per your needs. You can serialize and de-serialize objects using these helper methods.

```
public static string Serialize<T>(T objectToSerialize)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, objectToSerialize);
    return textWriter.ToString();
}


public static T Deserialize<T>(string stringToDeserialize)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    StringReader textReader = new StringReader(stringToDeserialize);
    return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(textReader);
}
```

How to Serialize object-to-string:

```
MyStructure myObject = GetPictureBoxObject();
string pbSerializedString = Serialize<MyStructure>(myObject);
```

How to DeSerialize string-to-object:

```
string str = GetStringToDeserialize();
MyStructure myObject = Deserialize<MyStructure>(str);
```