# How to create a collection of Shape objects?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, class, collections

I'm currently working on a user control in C # Winforms, which allows you to add a figure with properties each time from the designer with, so that you understand me better, I'll take a reference to the DataGridView, that every time a column is added, it has several parameters: Title, text alignment, etc, all within each object Column

Well, in my case I have this class:

```
public class Shape
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public ShapeType ShapeType { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public bool Mirrored { get; set; }
}
```

Well, my goal is to create a collection of Shape objects where in each Shape object their properties are encapsulated:

```
private List<Shape> shapelist = new List<Shape>();
public List<Shape> Shapes
{
    get => this.shapelist;
    set => this.shapelist = value;
}
```

Where do I add parameters when instantiating control from the Windows Forms designer:

```
public ShapesDecoration()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     Init();
}

public void Init()
{
     Shapes[0] = new Shape();
     Shapes[0].Width = 148;
     Shapes[0].Height = 64;
     Shapes[0].X = 20;
     Shapes[0].Y = 20;
     Shapes[0].Color = Color.DodgerBlue;
     Shapes[0].ShapeType = ShapeType.Circle;
}
```

To then call these parameters of each object in the list, for example, here I am calling the parameters of the Shape object in the first position:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
     base.OnPaint(e);
     Hector.Framework.Utils.ShapeCollection.FillCircle(e, Shapes[0].Color, Shapes[0].X, Shapes[0].Y, Shapes[0].Width, Shapes[0].Height);
}
```

My problem is that every time I drag the control to the form, Visual Studio shows me an error message which says that **Shape is not marked as serializable**

So, lists do not support classes like data types?

Or am I implementing something wrongly?

How can I create a collection of the Shape object, each object with its respective parameters?

Comment: Try marking it as `[Serializable]`

Comment: If you need design-time support, derive from component or implement IComponent. If your intention is saving those shapes into a file after a drawing, take a look at [this post]([How to save shapes which I draw on a Panel as binary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40575797/3110834)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple add attribute:

```
[Serializable]
public class Shape
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public ShapeType ShapeType { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public bool Mirrored { get; set; }
}
```